# Copy the HTML code from the url to the other file using PHP

Tags: php, file

I have the PHP code as below:

```
<?php
    $htmlFile = file_get_contents(http://archi-graphi.com/arcancianev/sejour-29-eau_turquoise_en_corse.html');
    $pdfHtml = ('pdfFile.html');
    copy($htmlFile, $pdfHtml);
        // Now you can choose to run a check to see if the new copy exists,
        // or you have the option to do nothing and assume it is made
        if (file_exists($pdfHtml)) {
            echo "Success :  has been made";
        } else {
            echo "Failure:  does not exist";
        }
?>
```

But I got the error messages `Warning: copy( <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="fr"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <title>Vacances Arcanciane</title> ...` I don know what is the error from.Anyone help me please,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're probably looking for [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead of [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php):

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents('http://archi-graphi.com/arcancianev/sejour-29-eau_turquoise_en_corse.html');
    $pdfHtml = 'pdfFile.html';

    // this is probably what you're trying to do
    file_put_contents($pdfHtml, $html);

        // Now you can choose to run a check to see if the new copy exists,
        // or you have the option to do nothing and assume it is made
        if (file_exists($pdfHtml)) {
            echo "Success :  has been made";
        } else {
            echo "Failure:  does not exist";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the order of variables for the copy. It should be `copy($pdfHtml, $htmlFile);` instead of `copy($htmlFile, $pdfHtml);`

Comment: `copy ( string $source , string $dest [, resource $context ] ) : bool` . Makes a copy of the file source to dest.